# :app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex FAILED in android studio

Tags: java, android

My Project is working fine but i added Direct Pay jar files. I have fond error like this:-

> Error:Execution failed for task 
>   ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.  java.util.zip.ZipException:
>   duplicate entry: com/toml/dp/util/AES128Bit.class

My gradle file:-

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.shoppingmazza"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/fluent-hc-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-win-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar')
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile files('libs/aes1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/aes5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/aes6.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: duplicate entry happen .

Comment: close your Android Studio. Go to your project directory and delete `build` and `app/build` directories. Run Android Studio - it should rebuild them

Comment: I close my studio and delete my build directories but same will come.

Comment: there is no pay jar file in my project.@ IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use one jar version from libs/aesX.X.jar .The AES128Bit.class is found multiple times on compilation because there is 3 jars of the same library included

Comment: did you try to clean up the project and rebuild it ?